# Multiple checking PHP

Tags: php, forms, function, authentication

I have this part of code:

```
<?PHP

function checkPass()
{
  $shkey = $_POST["shkey"];
  if($shkey <> "zCBh4beam6EPxJY569vqeh7JbYNdKKrY"){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
function checkLogin()
{
  $login = $_POST["login"];
  if($login <> "admin1"){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }
}
if(isSet($_POST["shkey"]) && checkPass()){
  include('acpXAS542.php');
}
else{
  echo("<HTML><BODY><CENTER>");
  echo("<H2>Niepoprawne hasło!</H2>");
  echo("</CENTER></BODY></HTML>");
}
?>
```

and I would like this script to verify the field named "login" but according two values, for example:
- admin1
- admin2

I don't know how to do that 'cause my skills in PHP are like silver 1 in **CS:GO**

Comment: `echo` is a language construct, so you need not use it as a method. `isset` instead of `isSet`. It won't throw errors but that's not the right way to go about it. Any special reason to use `<>` instead of `!=` or `!==`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify:

```
<?php

function checkPass($shkey)
{
    return $shkey == 'zCBh4beam6EPxJY569vqeh7JbYNdKKrY';
}
function checkLogin($login)
{
    return in_array($login, ['foo', 'bar']);
}
if(
    checkLogin($_POST['login'] ?? null) && 
    checkPass($_POST['shkey']  ?? null)
){
    echo 'good';
} else {
    echo 'bad';
}
```